# Console APP with Timer not running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, timer, console-application

I did this first into a WinForm project, now I've changed the application type to "Console application", I've deleted the form1.vb, changed the startup object to this "Module1.vb" but now I can't run the app.
well the app runs but the timer tick is doing nothing, the code is exactly the same, I only did one change for the **sub main/form1_load** name

What I'm doing wrong?

PS: I've tested if the error was in the conditional of the lock method and all is good there, the problem is with the ticker event but I don't know why.

```
#Region " Vars "

    Dim Running As Boolean = False
    Dim Errors As Boolean = False

    Dim Executable_Name As String = Nothing

    Dim Toogle_Key As System.Windows.Forms.Keys = Nothing
    Dim WithEvents Toogle_Key_Global As Shortcut = Nothing

    Dim Executable_Timer As New Timer
    Dim Lock_Timer As New Timer
    Dim Lock_Interval As Int32 = 10
    Dim Lock_Sleep As Int32 = Get_Milliseconds(3)

    Dim Screen_Center_X As Int16 = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 2)
    Dim Screen_Center_Y As Int16 = (Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2)

#End Region

    ' Load
Sub main()
    Pass_Args()
    Sleep()
    Lock()
End Sub

    ' Lock
Private Sub Lock()
    If Process_Is_Running(Executable_Name) Then
        AddHandler Lock_Timer.Tick, AddressOf Lock_Tick
        AddHandler Executable_Timer.Tick, AddressOf Executable_Tick
        Lock_Timer.Interval = Lock_Interval
        Lock_Timer.Start()
        Executable_Timer.Start()
        Running = True
    Else
        Terminate()
    End If
End Sub

' Lock Tick
Private Sub Lock_Tick()
    Console.WriteLine("test")
    If Running Then Cursor.Position = New Point(Screen_Center_X, Screen_Center_Y)
End Sub
```

> UPDATE

I made these changes like in the examples of MSDN:

```
Dim Executable_Timer As New System.Timers.Timer
Dim Lock_Timer As New System.Timers.Timer

AddHandler Lock_Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Lock_Tick
AddHandler Executable_Timer.Elapsed, AddressOf Executable_Tick
```

But the tick/elapsed is still doing nothing...

Comment: Without going to deep to understand all of your code. The `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` object can't work in a console application. You need a System.Timer

Comment: oh thankyou, but now the problem is with the tick event, can you tell me wich is the equivalent for this type of timer?

Comment: The event is called Elapsed, see example in my answer below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FROM MSDN

[Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx)

> Implements a timer that raises an event at user-defined intervals.
>   This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must
>   be used in a window.

You need a [System.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)
Of course this requires a different event Handling
(Example taken from MSDN)

```
    ' Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    Dim aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000)

    ' Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer.
    AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent

    ....

    Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)
         Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime)
    End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou so much i've followed the examples of MSDN but the elapsed event does nothing in my app! :( I can't see if there is another error in my code

Comment: Did you change the signature of Lock_Tick to be compatible with the Elapsed event?

Comment: I think not, how I can change that? but anyways the other timer (Executable timer elapsed event) is running good, I can't understand why this timer is not running.

Comment: The Lock_Tick event should receive the same parameters expected by the OnTimedEvent of the example.

Comment: but not need to specify the arguments and the "e" 'cause I'm not trying to pass any argument to the sub that handles that event or to use the object, anyway i've tested with and without that signature

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Windows.Forms.Timer` in console application if you add `Application.Run()` at the end of your `main()`.

This kind of timer might be useful in some console applications if you are using any offscreen `Windows.Forms` object - ie.: for offscreen rendering - these objects can't be simply accessed from `System.Timer` since it fires on separate thread (than the one where `Windows.Forms` object was created on).

Otherwise by all means use the `System.Timers.Timer` or `System.Threading.Timer`