# Timer inside console app doesn't trigger event

Tags: c#

I've tried to make a simple console application with timer tick event every second, but it's not working. Event doesn't trigger at all. Why is that?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15761110/2932057) - Use System.Timer instead of System.Windows.Timer in case of console application.

Comment: I've used System.Threading.Timer, that works.